# Как вывести предыдущий и следующий id новости из таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, имеем таблицу с id новостей:

`id |
5  |
7  |
15 |
20 |`

И запрос:

```
$query = "select * from articleviews order by articleid desc limit 1";
$results = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$lastid = mysql_fetch_array($results);

//Previous link
$previousid = $_GET['id']-1;
if ($previousid < 1) {
    $previous = "";
} else {
    $previous = '/article.php?id='.$previousid;
}

//Next link
$nextid = $_GET['id']+1;
if ($nextid > $lastid['id']) {
    $next = "";
} else {
    $next = '/article.php?id='.$nextid;
}
```

Но в итоге в ссылку вставляются только id по порядку от открытой новости.
Например, на новости, у которой id 15, предыдущая ссылка будет на новость с id 14, а не 7. Помогите вывести существующие id на новости.

Answer (score 5):

```
select 
   (select id 
       from articleviews
      where id < ?
      order by id desc 
      limit 1) as prev, 
    (select id 
        from articleviews
      where id > ?
      order by id 
      limit 1) as next
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется запросить идентификаторы следующей и предыдущей записей при помощи отдельных запросов.

Идентификатор предыдущей записи:

```
SELECT
  articleid AS previousid
FROM
  articleviews
WHERE
  articleid < $lastid
ORDER BY
  articleid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Идентификатор следующей записи:

```
SELECT
  articleid AS nextid
FROM
  articleviews
WHERE
  articleid > $lastid
ORDER BY
  articleid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь запросом:

```
select min(id) as prev,max(id) as next from
 (
  select id from articleviews
   where id>=(select coalesce(max(id),?) from articleviews where id < ?)
   order by id
   limit 3
 ) A
```

В место `?` надо привязать ваш текущий ID. На выходе в массиве результатов сразу лежат `prev` и `next`. Если полученные переменные равны текущему ID или NULL - значит заданный ID был первым или последним, не выводите такую ссылку.

Comment: А почему в первом `where` тогда не написать просто `id <= ? + 1`  Если ожидается совпадение по `id`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Возьмем `?`=15 по приведенному примеру в вопросе. тогда ?+1=16, берем 3 записи, которые <=16: 5,7,15. Мы не получили следующую ID за 15, т.е. 20 - поэтому именно так как написано

Comment: @Mike, я крутил-крутил в голове. не будет ваш запрос работать, если id = 1. Null, Null вернет

Comment: @splash58 Согласен, исправил, но как то слишком мудрено выходит :(

Comment: @Mike, мне кажется вы сразу очень казуистически к этому запросу подошли. хотя сама по себе идея неплоха - про три последовательных

Comment: @splash58 Не привык я к mysql. В окракле даже после адаптации ваш запрос не смог бы работать, потому что если подзапрос в списке выборки не найдет одну запись - то будет ошибка выполнения

Comment: а какие-нить джойны юнионы не спасут?  Я имею в виду эти два запроса объединить юнионом и взять мин и макс?

Comment: @splash58 union еще более громоздким выйдет

Comment: а вот такое в sql получится - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c4439/5 ? Единственно, он на краях будет оно и тоже возвращать, а не нуль

Comment: @splash58 Ну вот мне этот union и кажется громоздким. Я вспомнил, все началось с того, что я хотел на клиента отдельными строками отдать результат. А уже при написании ответа решил что одной строкой было бы лучше, вот и появился min/max из этого :)

Comment: понятно. хорошего дня!